# How would I disable the autocorrect in the Access VBA editor?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a issue where the VBA editor in Access 2013 is automatically camel casing a javaScript command I am sending to a web browser.  Since case does matter in javaScript, the camel casing causes an error because the the function "tmsCommand" does not exist (this should be "tmscommand").

Is there a way to disable to automatic camel casing in the VBA editor so that "tmscommand" can be entered verbatim?

Comment: The VBA editor normally only adjusts the character case for VBA code itself. I would have thought that any JavaScript commands in your code would be part of a string literal, and the VBA editor does not mess with those. Can you explain further how you are generating this JavaScript code?

Comment: Right click tmsCommand -> Definition ; does is show anything?

Comment: When I right click tmsCommand the message is "Identifier under cursor is not recognized".  The entire command is:

 WebBrowser0.Object.Document.parentWindow.tmsCommand ("TMS|SETCENTER|55,55,0")

If I deliberately misspell tmscommand (say tmsqommand), the VBA editor accepts it without correction.  I think it is simply camel-casing "Command".  I wonder if Access can be setup to use a third party editor.

Comment: Please paste your actual code, it looks like you are calling this on a VBA object which means that `tmsCommand` is not a javascript command but a VBA command on something which exists in the Access datamodel.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the top of your procedure and type

```
Dim tmscommand as Object
```

and press enter.  Now delete that line. The VBE will seemingly forever remember that case.

Comment: Thanks most kindly! I will give this a try.  I did do a search in the project for tmsCommand and found no additional instances.  I will try the declaration above.

Answer (score 0):

VBA is finding something concrete called `tmsCommand`, if you can figure out what it is then pass the moniker in a string:

```
WebBrowser0.Object.Document.parentWindow.execScript("tmsCommand('TMS|SETCENTER|55,55,0')")
```